# What does one mean by a covering space $Y_1$ dominates another covering space $Y_2$

Tags: fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

I was reading through the expository paper [https://math.berkeley.edu/~dcorwin/files/etale.pdf](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Edcorwin/files/etale.pdf) In chapter 1 section 1.1.2 the statement says

> We have $H_1 ⊆ H_2$ iff $Y_1$ dominates $Y_2$

It basically says given two covers $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ of a space X with $Y_1$ "dominating" $Y_2$, the fundamental group corresponding to $Y_1$( say $H_1$) and $Y_2$( say $H_2$) follows that $H_1 \subseteq H_2$

Here i clearly do not understand what does one mean by  covering space $Y_1$ dominates another covering space $Y_2$ . can someone please explain what it is and hoe this inclusion is justified.

Thank you

Comment: A covering $p_1: Y_1\to X$ dominates $p_2: Y_2\to X$ if there is a covering $q: Y_1\to Y_2$ such that $p_1=p_2\circ q$. For all reasonably nice topological spaces $X$ this condition can be expressed in terms of subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$. You will find this in any algebraic topology textbook, say, chapter 1 of Hatcher's book.